# Looking for a Reference for Solving a PDE Numerically

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question

What is the reference I should read to solve this PDE numerically ?
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - r (\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2})+\sin(y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$$
with the following periodic boundary conditions 
$$u(-\pi,y,t)=u(\pi ,y,t) \\
(u(x,-\pi,t)=u(x,\pi,t) \\
u_x(-\pi ,y,t)=u_x(\pi,y,t)\\
u_y(x,-\pi,t)=u_y(x,\pi,t) \\
u(x,y,0)=F(x,y) \\
r>0$$

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little about your background in the numerical solution of PDEs and what type of method you want to use? What you're looking at is a linear (assuming $r$ is a constant), two-dimensional advection-diffusion problem with variable wave-speed. What is the domain on which the PDE is defined? It matters because the sign of $\sin{(y)}$ affects where potential boundary conditions should be imposed.

Comment: I have studied a course solving linear pde using finite difference , and spectral methods for solving differential equation

Comment: I am thinking of using fourier collocation method or finite difference method and using mathematica to write a code is there any reference to read ?

Comment: I have studied finite difference from the book "Numerical solutions for partial differential equation " Author G.D.Smith but it doesn't help me to solve this problem